# ios: Mocking private properties

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, mocking, ocmock, xcasset

I want to mock an array which is private property inside my class. i have made it available in my unit test by doing this. (this is inside my unit test file)

```
@interface MyViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray myArray;

@end
```

Lets assume i have a type called `Person` and this array should contains person objects. So i am doing the following in my test case

```
- (void)testBeneficiariesCount {
    // This is an example of a functional test case.
    // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
    id mockArray = OCMClassMock([NSArray class]);

    self.myVC.myarray = mockArray;


    Person *p1 = [[Person alloc] init];
    Person *p2 = [[Person alloc] init];
    Person *p3 = [[Person alloc] init];
    Person *p4 = [[Person alloc] init];
    Person *p5 = [[Person alloc] init];

    p1.name = @“Alice"; p2.name = @“James”; p3.name = @“Oscar"; p4.name = @“Harri”; p5.name = @“John”;
    persons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,nil];


    OCMStub([self.myVC myArray]).andReturn(persons);

    XCTAssertEqual([self.myVC numberOfPersons], 5);

 }
```

myVC has a method named `numberOfPersons`, when i run this, test case is failing complaining that `(0) is not equal to (5)`. This means that i am not successfully able to mock my array, as i also tries to print the mocked array and it has nothing in it.

Can some please tell me what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a mock to stub onto, and from what it looks like, `self.myVC` is not a mock.

I'd recommend creating a [partial mock](http://ocmock.org/reference/#creating-mock-objects) for the view controller and stub afterwards.

```
MyViewController *partialMock = OCMPartialMock(self.myVC)

OCMStub([partialMock myArray]).andReturn(persons);

XCTAssertEqual([partialMock numberOfPersons], 5);
```

BTW, you don't need the `mockArray` usage if you're anyway be stubbing the `myArray` getter.